# Error inflating RecyclerView Unable to start activity

Tags: android

I have looked for an answer to my solution but the problem still exists after using attempting the solutions. Let me explain my problem

I have a fragment in Android named RedditListFragment. This fragment will display a recycler view. I have added the recycler view in my project by adding the library. The version is: com.android.support:recyclerview -v7:25.0.0. I have added the compile command in my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
```

So far everything is looking good. Now I create a layout file with root layout being RecyclerView. Here is what the layout looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/reddit_recycler_view"
tools:context="com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez.RedditListFragment">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Now I inflate the layout file in my code. I do so like this:

```
 package com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez;


  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;


 /**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class RedditListFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reddit_list, container, false);
          mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reddit_recycler_view);
          mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

   }
```

Now when I attempt to run the project I get this long exception which I dont understand.

```
12-03 16:16:21.518 11345-11345/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez, PID: 11345
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez/com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez.RedditListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                   at com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez.RedditListFragment.onCreateView(RedditListFragment.java:25)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6681)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getImportantForAccessibility(Landroid/view/View;)I in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/data/com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-v4-r7_98313a484a266aab27237a67f95cdf563fef0995-classes.dex)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:544)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:519)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                   at com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez.RedditListFragment.onCreateView(RedditListFragment.java:25) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6681) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I believe the source of the problem might be from here:
[image: Layout Eror]

**I have tried the following**: Invaldiate Caches/Restart. I did this numerous times. I have tried cleaning project/rebuild but does not work. I did this numerous times also. I tried building project then refreshing but I still get the same error.

If I can get any help I would really appreciate it. If theres some information that you need to help me I will be more than glad to provide it. I am a beginner Android dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines from your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
```

And replace them with these:

```
//Android Support SDK
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have relieved me from much pain. I have one follow up question if you do not mind. Why did this work? What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Managing dependencies is hard in some cases, you should try to keep them as simple as possible.

And the recyclerview dependency is actually part of the support:design dependency, which also include other different views such as CoordinatorLayout, and CardView.